# Bash разделитель строки

Tags: bash, shell

Есть файл:

```
name1:path1
name2:path2
name3:path3
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы поместить файлы с указанными именами в папки с указанными путями. Соответственно, надо сделать что-то похожее:

```
while read line;
do 
    set -- $line #Здесь хотелось бы указать ':' как разделитель 
    name=$1
    size=$2
    mv $1 $2
done </home/user/file
```

Comment: Либо %.%%.#.##. либо ещё вариант с `cut`.

Answer (score 2):

можно воспользоваться переменной `$IFS` (*input fields separator*), присвоив ей требуемый разделитель полей (двоеточие):

```
$ echo "n1:p1" | while IFS=: read n p; do echo "имя:$n путь:$p"; done
имя:n1 путь:p1
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно это не лучший вариант, но обычно разделяю строку вот так:

```
while read line;
do 
    set -- $line
    IFS=":"; declare -a lines=($*)
    ${lines[0]} #path
    ${lines[1]} #name
    mv ${lines[1]} ${lines[0]}
done </home/user/file
```